# How to convert a string to bytes in RHINO Js

Tags: javascript, rhino

If i use getBytes() method to convert a string to bytes in RHINO JS it shows method not found in Object list. So how to convert a string to bytes in rhino js.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = "abc";
var bytes = (new java.lang.String(str)).getBytes();
for (var b in bytes){
    print(bytes[b]);
}
```